# bootstrap collapse accordion when clicked panel-heading div, panel Grows, then normalizes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a collapse accordion on bootstrap 3.
 
I need use style **`float: left; width: 100%;`** for *.panel-heading* div. But this not working right. When clicked collapse this panel Grows, then normalizes. I don't want this. 
Anyone have a idea for this issue?
P.S Sorry my bad english.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/4562/)

Comment: what do want to accomplish using `float:left;` .maybe someone could suggest an alternative for this style

Comment: Thank you @AnujaAgarwal . I look closely and find a way. I use height instead of float. Float need me to panel-heading will height.

Comment: See this code: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Q6zjv

Comment: Thank your attention @Vishnu . But I needed other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove float from your style, instead you can use text-align

```
.panel-heading {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No, this not rigth way. Because, float property get my panel-heading div block element.

Comment: well you said removing float worked for you. didn't it

Comment: this text-align property keeps text of your heading in the left. I thought thats what you were trying to get with float

Comment: Yes, I remove float and add min-height for height.

Comment: It would be a win-win

Answer (score 0):

Please use only

```
.panel-heading { width:100%;}
```

Thanks,